Call same yaml template twice with same parameters but different value
I have a yaml template for azure devops pipeline in a repository which in general aspects does an Invoke-Command in a Machine $(Server).
repo.yml:
steps:
- powershell: |
     
     $SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $(LogInPassword) -Force
     $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $(LogInUser),$SecurePass 
     
     Write-Output $(Server)

     $Result = Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $(Server) -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock 

I have a template with the parameters of two machine with its value: ClientServer and AppServer.
parameters:
  AppServer: 'a'
  ClientServer: 'b'

jobs:
- job: Deploy
  variables:
    ClientServer: ${{ parameters.ClientServer }}
    AppServer: ${{ parameters.AppServer }}
    
  pool:
   name: pool
  workspace:
   clean: all
  timeoutInMinutes: 120
  steps:
  - template: ../main.yml

main.yml:
steps:
  - template: Install.yml

Now main.yml calls Install.yml
steps:
- template: repo.yml@templates
  parameters:
    Server: ${{ parameters.ClientServer }}

- template: repo.yml@templates
  parameters:
    Server: ${{ parameters.AppServer }}

In this template I want to call the template from the repository twice. One with the parameter AppServer and then with the parameter ClientServer.
The problem is that in the template I can just have one variable in the powershell $(Server).
The problem is that works at first call, but in the second the value of Server keep with ${{ parameters.ClientServer }}
$(LogInUser) and $(LogInPassword) are global variables from the pipeline.
What I want to achive: I do have two variables
ClientServer: ${{ parameters.ClientServer }}
AppServer: ${{ parameters.AppServer }}

I need to call the same template twice, one for ClientServer and a second for AppServer.
What I think it could work creating a parameter Server in the yaml that contains the value of ClientServer and then changes it values and setting AppServer as it value. But the problem that I've encountered is that the change of values doesn't work.
I've also tried this:
- ${{ each Server in parameters.Servers }}:
  - template: repo.yml@templates
    parameters:
      Server: ${{ Server }}

But it doesn't work.
As I cannot have two templates one for ClientServer and another for AppServer I have:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $(Server)


It would be useful if you could edit your question and post more code, such as repo.yml@templates's content.

Please also let us know how you define the variable $(Server), do you define it directly in repo.yml? or in the PowerShell script?

Are you pasting the whole template's content? I don't see parameters defined in repo.yml

And where are $(LogInUser) and $(LogInPassword) coming from?

@Mario_7626, i checked your yaml sample, and fix the code, the point is the parameter value should be defined and transferred to template correctly, please check the detail below, thanks.

It seems you're not using the parameters ${{ parameter.xxx }} passed to your repo.yml template.
Instead you're referencing variables defined/set elsewhere, like $(Server), $(LogInUser) and $(LogInPassword).
I'd recommend you to avoid using pipeline variables in steps templates.
In order to make repo.yml reusable I suggest you pass the server, username and password as parameters instead:
parameters:
  - name: Server
    displayName: 'Server name'
    type: string

  - name: LogInUser
    displayName: 'User'
    type: string

  - name: LogInPassword
    displayName: 'Password'
    type: string

steps:
  - powershell: |
      $server="${{ parameters.Server }}"
      $user="${{ parameters.LogInUser }}"
      $password="${{ parameters.LogInPassword }}"
      
      $SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force
      $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$SecurePass 
      
      Write-Output $server

      $Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock  

Please notice I'm setting script variables with the values of the parameters:
steps:
  - powershell: |
      $server="${{ parameters.Server }}"
      $user="${{ parameters.LogInUser }}"
      $password="${{ parameters.LogInPassword }}"

      # rest of script goes here

Using the template:
steps:
  - template: repo.yml@templates
    parameters:
      Server: ${{ parameters.ClientServer }}
      LogInUser: ${{ parameters.ClientLogInUser }}
      LogInPassword: ${{ parameters.ClientLogInPassword }}

  - template: repo.yml@templates
    parameters:
      Server: ${{ parameters.AppServer }}
      LogInUser: ${{ parameters.AppLogInUser }}
      LogInPassword: ${{ parameters.AppLogInPassword }}

EDIT 1:
As suggested by @Styxxy, we can define environment variables in the task, instead of setting script variables.
Something like this:
- powershell: |
    $SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Env:LogInPassword -Force
    $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Env:LogInUser,$SecurePass 
    
    Write-Output $Env:Server

    $Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Env:Server -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock 
  env:
    Server: ${{ parameters.Server }}
    LogInUser: ${{ parameters.LogInUser }}
    LogInPassword: ${{ parameters.LogInPassword }}


I recommend to use environment variables in the Powershell task, rather than injecting the values in the script itself (so the password won't be hardcoded and plain text visible in the temporary powershell file).

@Styxxy good point. But if the parameter is set from a secret variable it shouldn't be displayed in the pipeline logs.

@RuiJarimba outside of repo.yml, where should I define Server?
Just
parameters:
Server: ${{ parameters.ClientServer }}
in Install.yml or should I defien as a variable or parameter before?

Server is a parameter of repo.yml. You invoke the template either using parameters such as Server: ${{ parameters.AppServer }}, Server: ${{ parameters.ClientServer }} or variables such as Server: $(AppServer), Server: $(ClientServer) defined/set elsewhere. For example, you can declare these parameters or variables at the pipeline level, i.e. in the main file where the other templates are used.

@Mario_7626 was my explanation clear?

@RuiJarimba True that it will be masked in the logs, but it is about the physical access of the temporary file (the files get normally deleted), but there are cases the delete doesn't happen (eg server crash) and then the secret can be easily read from the temp files ;).

@Styxxy yep, that's true :-)

@RuiJarimba I understand that when I pass Server: ${{ parameters.AppServer }} or Server: ${{ parameters.ClientServer }} as parameter to the repo template It is "defined" and I don't need to mention Server anywhere else. Then I defined the parameter Server at the template and pass it to the powerhsell. What I don't understand is what I'm doing wrong because it is not working to me.

@Mario_7626 what exactly does it mean it is not working for me? Is there any error? Have you changed your template to use parameters, just like in my example? as a starting point, try just printing the parameters values to the screen to see if the values are right.

@RuiJarimba $Server keeps undefined in the powershell

@Mario_7626 there was a small typo in the first template - it should be Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server instead of Invoke-Command -ComputerName $(Server). My apologies

I've changed the value. But thank you for your time.

@Mario_7626 were you able to make it work?

It appears you have several yaml templates:
start yaml -> main.yml -> install.yml -> repo.yaml
when you transfer the parameter value, you need to make sure it have correct value delivered.
On your install.yml, make sure it has parameter defined, as you need to deliver the parameter value.
#install.yml

parameters:
 - name: AppServer
   default: 'a'
 - name: ClientServer
   default: 'b'

steps:
- template: repo.yml@templates
  parameters:
    Server: ${{ parameters.ClientServer }}

- template: repo.yml@templates
  parameters:
    Server: ${{ parameters.AppServer }}

In repo.yml, define parameter again to receive. use $server= "${{ parameters.server }}" to set the server value. I commented other strings, you can add it back.
parameters:
  - name: server
    default: default

steps:
- powershell: |
    $server= "${{ parameters.server }}"
    Write-Output $Server
    #$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $(LogInPassword) -Force 
    #$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $(LogInUser),$SecurePass
    # $Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock


The pipeline result, get a, b for server:

You can also define variable value in install.yml for parameter value:
#install.yml
parameters:
 - name: AppServer
   default: $(AppServer)
 - name: ClientServer
   default: '$(ClientServer)'

steps:
- template: repo.yml@templates
  parameters:
    Server: ${{ parameters.ClientServer }}

- template: repo.yml@templates
  parameters:
    Server: ${{ parameters.AppServer }}

But on start yaml, you need to define the variable value firstly, it works as well.

If you would like to use ${{ each Server in parameters.Servers }}:, you need to the parameter Servers definition.
change the install.yml content:
#install.yml
parameters:
- name: servers
  type: object
  default:
    - a
    - b

steps:
- ${{ each server in parameters.servers }}:
  - template: repo.yml@templates
    parameters:
      server: ${{ server }}

